# Detect file update from modification time

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems, io, tail

Is there a way to see how often a file is being updated?
I mean I need to see if the modification time of a file is updated in a dynamic way (same as `tail` shows if the file is updated in a dynamic way).
I can not use e.g. `tail` since the contents of the file are not appended, but overwritten and could be overwriten with the same value so I can not make a concusion.

Comment: http://www.noah.org/wiki/Inotify,_FAM,_Gamin

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
watch -n 1 'stat /path/to/the/file'
```

Comment: I see this:`Modify: 2013-02-22 04:25:07.000000000 -0500` the timestamp would dynamically increase had the file been constantly updated, correct?

Comment: Yes, just try it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [inotifywait](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywatch) to do this much more efficiently for example

```
inotifywait -e modify -m  --timefmt "%F %T" --format "%T %e" /tmp/fred/1
```

Will watch the file /tmp/fred/1 for modify events so updading it produces output like

```
2013-02-22 09:30:26 MODIFY
2013-02-22 09:30:26 MODIFY
```

You can log multiple events, change the time format (the timefmt takes [strftime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) formatting) output to a file and daemonize e.g

```
inotifywait -o /tmp/watch.out -d -e modify -m  --timefmt "%F %T" --format "%T %e" /tmp/fred/1
```

so now you can just tail /tmp/watch.out.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use 'audit' daemon
/etc/audit/auditd.conf is configuration file for audit daemon
/etc/audit/audit.rules contains audit rules